# In `gplots` in `R`, how can we adjust the position of the x-label ticks in the `heatmap.2` function?

Tags: r, gplots

I am trying to duplicate a plot found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4287945/bin/supp_btu622_btu622_supplement_v5.pdf) on pg. 4:

[image]

The reproducible code for it is:

```
require(devtools)
install_git("https://github.com/marchion/git.switchBox", subdir="switchBox")
require(switchBox)
require(gplots)
data(trainingData)    
classifier <- SWAP.KTSP.Train(matTraining, trainingGroup)
kappa <- SWAP.KTSP.Statistics(matTraining, classifier)
mat <- t(1*kappa$comparisons)
rownames(mat) <- gsub(">", "\n more express than\n", rownames(mat))

heatmap.2(mat,
scale="none", Rowv=F, Colv=F, dendrogram="none",
trace="none", key=FALSE,
col=c("lightsteelblue2", "pink3"),
labCol=toupper(paste(trainingGroup, "Prognosis")),
sepwidth=c(0.075,0.075), sepcolor="black",
rowsep=1:ncol(kappa$comparisons),
colsep=1:nrow(kappa$comparisons),
lmat=rbind( c(0, 3), c(2, 1), c(0, 4) ), lhei=c(0.1, 5, 0.5), lwid=c(0.15, 5),
mar=c(7.5, 12), cexRow=0.85, cexCol=0.9)
```

If you notice in the plot above, the x-labels are slightly off-center to the left. Is there a command inside the `heatmap.2` function that can shift each label to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify argument `adjCol` (`c(1, 0.5)`) would give you wanted result (`c(1, 0)` would move it to the left and `c(1, 1)` would move it more to the right).

Code (using OPs provided packages and data):

```
heatmap.2(
  mat,
  adjCol = c(1, 0.5), 
  scale = "none", Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none",
  trace = "none", key = FALSE,
  col = c("lightsteelblue2", "pink3"),
  labCol = toupper(paste(trainingGroup, "Prognosis")),
  sepwidth = c(0.075,0.075), sepcolor = "black",
  rowsep = 1:ncol(kappa$comparisons),
  colsep = 1:nrow(kappa$comparisons),
  lmat = rbind( c(0, 3), c(2, 1), c(0, 4) ),
  lhei = c(0.1, 5, 0.5), lwid = c(0.15, 5),
  mar = c(7.5, 12), cexRow = 0.85, cexCol = 0.9,
)
```

Result:

[image]